# Mac Outlook 2011

Tags: macos, imac, ms-office

I am using an iMac with Outlook 2011 installed. Until last week, there was no issue. Now, when I open Outlook, it initializes but does not open.

I tried rebuilding the database, twice. After Googling, I found instructions to delete com.Microsoft.outlook.plist file, restart the system and test if it works.
I did so, and now every time I want to use outlook. I need to delete the same file to open outlook.

I tried to re-install office 2011, without success.

Comment: Open console in `/Application/Utilities/` and then outlook. Then copy the console output onto [pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com) In the meantime, try to repair disk permissions on HD in Disk Utility in `/Applications/Utilities/` and include a link to the page you got the delete plist from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with the latest 14.5.0 update:

https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/office-2011-14-5-0-and-outlook-main-window-invisibility/

I suggest you update to 14.5.1 which contains a fix for this problem:

https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=47307